# Vertical Menu Not Going All The Way Down

Tags: browser, menu, stretch

I'm a few months old web designer and I'm having problems trying to make my vertical menu all the way down. Whenever I make my browser window smaller the vertical menu won't stretch until the bottom of the browser window.

P.s: I'm not able to post any images

Please tell me what I need to do to solve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
- Stanley

Comment: What code are you using?  What have you tried so far to resolve?

Comment: Hi Joel, I think the code for the vertical menu is jQuery. I tried :-
1. setting my <body> height to 100% for both my menu and the page's body
2. set overflow: hidden and position: absolute to the menu
and so far none of them are working.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?